# ODBC/JDBC connection details for USQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, u-sql

We are using Microsoft Azure USQL for database testing.
Can anyone please provide the ODBC/JDBC connection details for USQL?

Answer (score 0):

U-SQL is currently only available in the Azure Data Lake in a batch job form factor. This means that there is currently no ODBC/JDBC connectivity available since it is not giving you the ability to pass results directly to the providers.

So the programmatic way to submit U-SQL jobs is to use any of the available SDKs (Java, C#, Powershell, node.js, Python once available) to submit the job and then download the generated files as results.

We are working on an interactive form factor for U-SQL as well, but that is still a bit out.